# Please verify my proof of: $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Bbb Q}[\alpha,+\infty)=\Bbb R$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Bbb Q}[\alpha,+\infty)=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let, for $\alpha \in \Bbb Q,\ A_{\alpha}:=[\alpha,+\infty)\subset\Bbb R.$ I shall prove that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Bbb Q}A_{\alpha}=\Bbb R$ whereas $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Bbb Q}A_{\alpha}=\varnothing.$

Proof of $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Bbb Q}A_{\alpha}=\Bbb R:$

I'm going to prove that the set of rational numbers and the set of irrational numbers are included in the union of the sets $A_{\alpha}$.

1. By definition of the union of the sets $A_{\alpha}$, the set of rational numbers is included in the union of the sets $A_{\alpha}$
2. Using proof by contradiction, suppose that some irrational number $i$ does not belong to the union of the sets $A_{\alpha}$.
   (The irrational number is one or several, and if there are several, let's think only of the smallest of them.)

2-1. However, since there is always a rational number smaller than an irrational number
(this can be proved by the fact that an irrational number on a number line lies between two integers. If we do not use a number line, it can be proved that there is an integer between the irrational numbers i and i-1 and an integer between i and i+1),
a rational number $r$ less than some irrational number $i$ is included in the union of the sets $A_{\alpha}$.

2-2. Therefore, there is no such irrational number since some irrational number $i$ satisfies the condition ($x\ge\alpha$) to be an element of the union of sets $A_\alpha$.

2-3. Thus, the assumption is false and the set of irrational numbers is included in the union of sets $A_\alpha.$

2-4. Both the set of rational numbers and the set of irrational numbers are included in the union of sets $A_\alpha$, and by the condition that "the elements of union of the sets $A_\alpha$ is real numbers ($x \in\Bbb R$)", thus the union of sets $A_\alpha$ is equal to $\Bbb R.$

Proof of $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Bbb Q}A_{\alpha}=\varnothing:$

1. Using proof by contradiction, suppose that this intersection has at least one element that is a real number.
2. in the given condition, $x≥\alpha$. Therefore, the intersection must contain a rational number ${\alpha}$ as the smallest element. However, since the set of rational numbers is closed under addition. so by the rational number + the rational number (i.e by adding another rational number to ${\alpha}$) it is possible to create another intersection with the smallest element ${\alpha}_2$ greater than ${\alpha}$. This is a contradiction. Therefore, the intersection is the null set.

PS:
Yesterday I posted a proof verification question for a different problem from this one and it was deleted by vote. So I'm trying to refrain from posting proof verification questions. But this problem is a different problem and it is a problem that I proved by spending one day out of two days thinking about it. so I was curious and I posted a question. I apologize in advance.

I do not want specific proof verification, but I would like to know if it is roughly correct or not.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009292)

Comment: Do you have a source for this problem?  This helps determine what facts you are allowed to take for granted in the proof.  For example, is "for any real $r \in \mathbb{R}$, there is some $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a \le r$" a fact that you are allowed to take for granted in the proof?  This essentially trivializes the first proposition ($\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}} A_{\alpha} = \mathbb{R}$), but your proof uses the stronger fact that every irrational number lies between two integers (or equivalent).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the Proofreading and the link! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: "The irrational number is one or several, and if there are several, let's think only of the smallest of them.)" there may be no smallest. Better think only of one of them without telling which one. Even better: reason directly instead of by contradiction.

Comment: Your sentence *... in the given condition, $x≥\alpha$. Therefore, the intersection must contain a rational number ${\alpha}$ as the smallest element...* is also an issue. For example, $\bigcap I_n$ where $I_n = [1/n , \infty)$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ doesn't have a rational number as a smallest element.

Comment: @L.F. Sorry for the late reply, it took me a while to understand comments and think how to reply... This problem is from "Topics in Algebra" written by Herstein. The paragraph before this sentence introduces the concept of a family of sets F and an index set T and states that an index set can be any set, either infinite or finite, although index sets are usually used as non-negative integers set.

Comment: @L.F. The problem itself is like this:"If R is the set of real numbers, and If Q is the set of rational numbers, let, for α∈Q, Aα={x∈R l x≥α}, and prove that 'Union of the sets Aα = R', 'Intersection of the sets Aα = ∅'"

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh i see... I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge... actually I only have math knowledge of the first year of high school, and I just tried to prove it for fun(I'm sorry if this sounds somewhat arrogant(?)). I'm sorry. I will think about your advice and try to understand the reason you said that unceasingly. Thank you for your advices and help!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Um... Sorry, I will think about what you said. actually it's a bit hard to picture it in my head for me now... I'm sorry but I will deeply think about your advice. Thank you for your help! So... now I know there are many errors in my proof. I'm appreciate for advice of all of you. Thank you very much!